# Regex Expression to Match this: 090129 YBB 100

Tags: regex

Writing a quick app to help me filter text files.

I'm reading in a text file line-by-line, and need to match a series of characters that looks like this: 090129 YBB 100

The first set, 090129, will be 6 numbers (0-9). Followed by a space, and then YBB - always. After that, another space, then 2-3 numbers (0-9).

This pattern will always be the first part of the string as well.

**Here's my hack at it:**

```
^[0-9][0-9][0-9] (YBB) [0-9][0-9][0-9]\b
```

Of course, doesn't work... but I'm a regex noob. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here goes:

```
^([\d]{6})\s(?:YBB)\s([\d]{2,3})\b
```

Explanation:

a) Start at start of line.
b) Match 6 digits. Save into backref 1.
c) Match a space.
d) Match "YBB". Don't save into backref.
e) Match a space.
f) Match 2-3 digits. Save into backref 2.

Of course, it's important to know which part of this pattern you want to retrieve into a backreference. If you provide that info, I can edit my post.

Comment: I'm assuming you want to retrieve the digital part of the pattern. Edited my post and explanation.

Answer (score 2):

In Perl, I'd do:

```
^(\d{3}) YBB (\d{2,3})$
```

Answer (score 0):

This webtool might be able to help you: http://www.txt2re.com/

For this case in particular: http://www.txt2re.com/index-javascript.php3?s=090129%20YBB%20100&-23&12&19&13&16&18&20&7&-3&8&17&14&15

Answer (score 0):

You say there will be 6 digits before YBB, but the regex you show has only 3.

Comment: lol, true that! oh man, I'm bad at regex. Thanks for pointing that out.